# Prove or disprove $2^{an} = O(2^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, asymptotics

I was wondering if someone could verify or correct my work.

For all $a \ge 1$ Prove or Disprove $2^{an}$ belongs to big-o of $2^n$

By definition, if there is a positive integer '$N$' and a positive integer '$c$' then $f(n) \ge g(n)$, for all $n > N$.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
2^{an} &\le c\times2^n\\
\log(2^{an}) &\le c\times \log(2^n)\\
an\times \log(2) &\le cn\times \log(2)\\
an &\le cn
\end{align}

let
$$ c = 1 $$
$$ n = 1 $$
Therefore,
$$ a <= 1 $$
therefore our given statement cannot be true since there exists some 'a' >= 'c'

Comment: Your reasoning, although incorrect, does lead to the correct conclusion (that $2^{an}$ is not in $O(2^n)$ for all $a\ge 1$).  The step that says let $c=1$ is not justified, nor is the combined step taking $n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that $$\frac{2^{an}}{2^n} = 2^{(a-1)n}\to \infty$$ as $n\to \infty$. Which proves that $2^{an}$ is not $\mathcal O\left(2^n\right)$.

Comment: (unless $a=1$ of course!)

Answer (score 3):

The error is the second line:

$2^{an}\le c\times2^n \Rightarrow \log(2^{an}) \le c\times \log(2^n)$.

In fact

$2^{an}\le c\times2^n \Rightarrow \log(2^{an}) \le \log(c) +\log(2^n)$.

You should not assign a value to $n$. Why? Because you want to find a value $c$ that works for all $n$.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I think I see your point but does log(c) matter since by definition it's just "some" constant ergo log(c) could conceivably be written as just c? I see your point about defining n and c. There isn't a good reason to do so.

Comment: Yes, you could write "some" constant. Note that the point here is just the fact that the operation is addiction and not multiplication.

Comment: Maybe your point would be more clearly stated as: $an \in O(n)$ but $2^{an} \not\in O(2^n)$?